# Scraping over multiple pages using BeautifulSoup and dataframe iterrows

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to scrape from multiple URLs. The URL iterates by appending a variable I have saved in a dataframe (postcode_URL).

The code breaks on line: `table_rows = table.find_all('tr')`, throwing the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Interestingly, the code works perfectly if I remove the iteration and manually enter a single postcode in the URL, so I believe it must be something to do with the iteration loop.

Below is the code that I have used. Any ideas?

```
scraped_data = []

for x, row in postcodes_for_urls.iterrows():
    page = requests.get("http://myurl"+(row['postcode_URL']))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        scraped_data.append(row)

pd.DataFrame(scraped_data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Comment: I will suggest using scrapy (https://scrapy.org/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the problem and tried few snippets on my laptop.

The problem is not with the **DataFrame** , as you are reading each row at a time in the loop, the problem is with the URL, your program correctly scraps the page having table in it and throws an error for a postcode URL that doesn't have  element.

Consider the first test :

I created an HTML page without table in it :

```
 <html>
  <head>
     <title>Demo page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
     <h2>Demo without table</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then I executed the python code as below :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
data = open('table.html').read()
parser = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
table = parser.find('table')
rows = table.find_all('tr')
print(rows)
```

Above code stopped due to **NoneType exception** because **parser.find()** returns a **NoneType object** if table element is not found in the html data. So **find_all()** is not a method of NoneType object, thus it throws an error.

So I changed my HTML code as below :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>Demo without table</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>Demo</tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the python code works well without any exception as table element is present.

So the conclusion :

The exception is because one of the postcode in the DataFrame is leading to an URL that does not contain a table. So, I recommend you to make a small change to your code :

```
scraped_data = []

for x, row in postcodes_for_urls.iterrows():
  page = requests.get("http://myurl"+(row['postcode_URL']))
  soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
  table = soup.find('table')
  #add this :
  if table == None :
      continue

  table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
  for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    scraped_data.append(row)
```

pd.DataFrame(scraped_data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])

Comment: Amazing, this works perfectly now - thank you for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to put a check on `table_rows` if its None and its not empty, try below code. You can also put an `exception handler` like `try` and `catch` statement for best practices. It always breaks because of either an empty row or because of unusual patter on real page you are scraping.

```
scraped_data = []

for x, row in postcodes_for_urls.iterrows():
    page = requests.get("http://myurl"+(row['postcode_URL']))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')

    if table is not None and len(table.find_all('tr'))>0:
        table_rows = table.find_all('tr')
        for tr in table_rows:
            td = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [tr.text for tr in td]
            scraped_data.append(row)
    else:
        scraped_data.append('EMPTY')

pd.DataFrame(scraped_data, columns=["A", "B", "C"])
```

Comment: Yep, got it. Makes sense now. Thank you.